# How do I create a nested for loop using an array to pull specific numbers from a group of numbers in java?

Tags: java, arrays

So, I'm trying to create a nested for loop to pull all of the even numbers from a group of numbers but I want it to stop at 238 instead of going all the way through all of the numbers. Here is what I have gotten so far, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong. To be more specific, I need to be able to read all of the numbers listed below, and then pull all of the even numbers in the order that they are shown going no higher than 238.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {
            951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544, 
            615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941, 
            386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 
            399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 
            815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 
            958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470, 
            743, 527};

        int[] arr = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int el = arr[i];
            System.out.println(el);
        }

        int[] input = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < 238; i++) {
            for (i = 0; i < 238; i++) {
                if ( i >= 237) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi shellbyy, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you include what the current behavior is, vs. what you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

- filter all values are less or equal than required (`max = 238`)
- filter all even values

---

```
public static int[] findAllEvenNumbers(int[] arr, int max) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                    .filter(v -> v <= max)
                    .filter(v -> (v & 1) == 0).toArray();
}
```